# Perl - Count total number of word in file using subroutine method

Tags: perl, word-count

I tried to count the total number of words which are present in the file. The code below is showing 0 words as an output. Please help me fix this problem.

This code is saved in `Countsample.pm`:

```
package Countsample;

use strict;
use base"Exporter";
#use 5.010;

our @EXPORT=();
our @EXPORT_OK=qw(word_count);

sub word_count
{
    open(IP,"test1.txt");
    while(my $line=<>)
    my $word_count;


    my @words_on_line = split;
    $word_count+= @words_on_line;


    print"File contains $word_count words\n";
}

1;
```

Now in main program which is saved in `Countsample1.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Countsample qw(word_count);
word_count();
exit;
```

The output I am getting is

```
syntax error at Countsample.pm line 14, near ")
my "
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 14.
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 18.
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at Countsample1.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Countsample1.pl line 3.
```

Comment: Posting a question on StackOverflow every time you get a syntax error isn't a great way to learn to program. You need to develop the analytical skills to fix these problems yourself. The error shows you where the problem is (well, within a line or two). What stops you taking a close look at those lines and working out what went wrong for yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your program either a file or some input. E.g.

```
 perl Countsample1.pl Countsample.pm
```

will count the words in `Countsample.pm`

Also, you want `while (my $line = <>)` instead of the `open`. Did you notice how you never read from anything? I am assuming this is homework, so I am not going to post a completely re-written script.

Now, you must decide whether you are going to count words in just `test1.txt`, or anything given on the commandline or `STDIN` (that's what using `<>` means).

Assuming the latter, your `word_count` subroutine becomes rather simpler:

```
sub word_count {
    my $count;
    while (my $line=<>) {
        my @words_on_line = split ' ', $line;
        $count += @words_on_line;
    }
    print "File contains $count words\n";
    return; # don't accidentally use the return value of print as count
}
```

Of course, it would be better to just return the count from this subroutine and have the caller decide what to do with the return value.

PS: [Your shebang line is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script/2429515#2429515). It should be `#!/usr/bin/perl` if you want to use the system `perl`.

PPS: You don't need to inherit from [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter). In most cases,

```
use Exporter qw( import );
```

is all you need.

PPPS: Don't export stuff by default. Instead, do:

```
our @EXPORT = (); # nothing is exported by default
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( word_count ); # word_count is exported if asked
```

and then use

```
use Countsample qw( word_count );
```

so you can invoke `Countsample::word_count` as just `word_count`.

Comment: sir after correcting all these u suggested, than also its showing same output as mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

There are some syntax errors in your script :

```
sub word_count {
    open(my $IP, '<', 'test1.txt') or die $!;
    #                              ^^^^^^^^^ always test the result of open                             
    my $word_count;
    # you must defined the counter outside of the while loop
    while(my $line=<$IP>) {
        #                 ^ you missed begin while bloc
        my @words_on_line = split ' ', $line;
        $word_count+= @words_on_line;
    } # and close while bloc
    # print the total outside of the loop
    print"File contains $word_count words\n";
}
```

Comment: hii JE, the above script is also not working, i am not getting any output in output screen !!!!

Comment: @AdityaAcharya: do you have any error message? Put some debug in the sub to see what happen.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: You're right, I haven't taken these mistakes into account. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the error I get:

```
$ perl Countsample1.pl
syntax error at Countsample.pm line 14, near ")
    my "
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 14.
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 18.
Global symbol "$word_count" requires explicit package name at Countsample.pm line 21.
Compilation failed in require at Countsample1.pl line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Countsample1.pl line 1.
```

Lines 13 and 14 are:

```
while(my $line=<>)
my $word_count;
```

Your `while` loop needs a block of code. And blocks of code are delimited with braces. I think those lines (and the few following ones) should be:

```
my $word_count;
while(my $line=<>) {
    my @words_on_line = split;
    $word_count+= @words_on_line;
}
```

I've also moved `my $word_count` outside of the loop - you really don't want to reset it to zero on each loop iteration, do you?

Hmm.. now when I run it it just hangs. What could be wrong? That usually means either an infinite loop or a program waiting for input.

In this case, it's the program waiting for input.

```
while(my $line=<>)
```

This reads from STDIN (ok, yes, actually it reads from either STDIN or the files which have been passed on the command line - but there weren't any in this example, so STDIN it is). Presumably, you want it to read from the filehandle that have just opened. So use that instead.

```
while(my $line=<IP>)
```

Now it doesn't hang. But it says that my test file contains 0 words. And that's wrong.

Ah the problem is here. `my $line=<IP>` puts the line into `$line`. But you split the line with just `split`, which works on `$_`, not `$line`. Let's remove the `my $line=` so that the `while` loop puts the data into `$_`.

```
while (<IP>)
```

Now the program says that my file contains 5 words. Which is better than zero, but probably not right. So there's likely to be a logic problem.

Now you start debugging you logic...

**Update:** Actually, no. My file did contain only five words. So the logic is sound. Time to start adding more features. And perhaps modernising your code - for example replacing your old-style `open()` statement (`open(IP,"test1.txt")`) with something more modern (`open my $ip, '<', "test1.txt")`). Also check the return value from `open()` - `open my $ip, '<', "test1.txt") or die $!`.